# How to sum while iterating through an exponential equation in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, math

Real and imaginary parts of any complex function are related by the Kramer-Kronig relations (KKR). I am trying to use KKR modified for a logarithmic scale

[image]

where `X_R` is the real part of the modulus, `X_{R_{0}}` is the real modulus at some reference frequency `f_0`, `e` is Euler's number, and `L` is the number of frequencies `f_i` corresponding to the number of phase angles `\phi_i`.

However, I am unable since I am not quite sure how to sum an exponential equation in `Python`. I tried the following

```
import math
import numpy as np

f_exp  = np.array([.1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 20, 30, 40, 100])

x_exp  = np.array([2.69672131, 2.703278689, 2.71311475, 2.718032787, 2.721311475, 2.732240437, 2.743715847, 2.749726776, 2.773224044, 2.800546448,
                   2.81147541, 2.813114754, 2.81420765, 2.810928962, 2.810382514, 2.808196721, 2.808743169, 2.804371585, 2.807650273, 2.809289617, 
                   2.81256830])

qx_exp = np.array([0.004198813, 0.010331355, 0.017057369, 0.021656775, 0.023832839, 0.026849654, 0.027492582, 0.027987141, 0.025365974, 0.01418892, 
                   0.008204748, 0.006918892, 0.004990109, 0.003803165, 0.004050445, 0.003654797, 0.002912957, 0.002616222, 0.002319486, 0.00202275, 
                   0.001577646])

phases = [np.rad2deg(np.arctan(qx)) for qx in qx_exp]

def KKR(X_R0, frequency, phis):
    X_R = []
    for idx, i in enumerate(frequency):
        X_R[idx] = X_R0 * np.exp((1/(math.pi*math.log10(math.e))*np.sum(phis[idx+1]+phis[idx]*np.log10(frequency[idx+1]/frequency[idx]))))
    return X_R

kkr = KKR(x_exp[0], f_exp, phases)
```

where `f_exp` is frequency, `x_exp` is the real modulus, `qx_exp` is inverse Quality-factor, and `phases` are the phase angles but it obviously did not work.

What am I doing wrong? How do I sum while iterating through an exponential equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error, and with the help of @pythonic833, who helped me understand how to sum a series, I came up with the solution to my problem.

```
def KKR(modulus, frequency, phase):
    X_R0      = modulus[0]
    f         = frequency
    phi       = phase
    phi_sum   = [phi[i+1]+phi[i] for i in range(len(phi)-1)]
    f_div     = [f[i+1]/f[i] for i in range(len(f)-1)]
    log_f_div = np.log10(f_div)
    arg       = phi_sum*log_f_div
    series    = np.array([sum(arg[:i+1]) for i in range(len(arg))])
    exponent  = 1/(math.pi*math.log10(math.e)) * series
    X_R       = X_R0 * np.exp(exponent)
    X_R       = np.insert(X_R, 0, X_R0)
    return X_R
```

Thank you again, @pythonic833!

Answer (score 1):

You are summing `X_R0**exp1 + X_R0**exp2` and so on instead of summing the exponents first and the exponenanting:

```
import math
import numpy as np

f_exp  = np.array([.1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 20, 30, 40, 100])

x_exp  = np.array([2.69672131, 2.703278689, 2.71311475, 2.718032787, 2.721311475, 2.732240437, 2.743715847, 2.749726776, 2.773224044, 2.800546448,
                   2.81147541, 2.813114754, 2.81420765, 2.810928962, 2.810382514, 2.808196721, 2.808743169, 2.804371585, 2.807650273, 2.809289617, 
                   2.81256830])

qx_exp = np.array([0.004198813, 0.010331355, 0.017057369, 0.021656775, 0.023832839, 0.026849654, 0.027492582, 0.027987141, 0.025365974, 0.01418892, 
                   0.008204748, 0.006918892, 0.004990109, 0.003803165, 0.004050445, 0.003654797, 0.002912957, 0.002616222, 0.002319486, 0.00202275, 
                   0.001577646])

phases = [np.rad2deg(np.arctan(qx)) for qx in qx_exp]

def KKR(X_R0, frequency, phis):
    X_R = []
    exponent = 0
    prefactor =  1/(math.pi*math.log(math.e))
    for idx in range(len(frequency)-1): # calculate sum of exponents
        exponent += prefactor*np.sum(phis[idx+1]+phis[idx]*np.log(frequency[idx+1]/frequency[idx]))
    X_R = X_R0 ** exponent # apply the resulting exponent
    return X_R 

kkr = KKR(x_exp[0], f_exp, phases)
```

Comment: Thank you, @pythonic833. I just saw that I had provided the wrong equation (I confused `np.exp()` for `**` as well as `math.log10` and `np.log10` for `math.log` and `np.log`, so I edited the question accordingly) -- I apologize for that. However, `X_R` should be a vector, not a single variable. Do you have any ideas on how to achieve that?

Comment: so is `X` dependent on `t` and this relation must be fuilfilled at all times? I don't now the KKR in the form you provided

Comment: Yes, `X_R` depends on `f_exp` so it is frequency- and thus time-dependent. I managed to do what I was supposed (recreating the result from an article) in the answer below. Thank you for setting me on the right course though, @pythonic833!